# Elasticsearch stops suddenly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I've recently upgraded my 3 node cluster to elastic 2.4.2 from 1.5.
Since the upgrade (I think), I experience random shutdowns of the elasticsearch service: about once a day (at no specific hour), one of the nodes stops working- every time a different node.
I turned on DEBUG logging for the root logger, but there's nothing interesting there, it just stops with:

> recalculating shard indexing buffer, total is [815.8mb] with [2]
>   active shards, each shard set to indexing=[407.9mb], translog=[64kb]

I looked at the syslog, and there was nothing interesting there also.

I'm running on m4.xlrage EC2 machines with 16GB RAM. 
Settings in elasticsearch.yml that are not the default:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 75%
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: 85%
discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout: 60s
discovery.zen.fd.ping_retries: 5
```

and in /etc/default/elasticsearch:

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=8g
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you allocated sufficient memory in `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu with a debian package, so the memory settings are at /etc/default/elasticsearch. I've allocated 8g for ES_HEAP_SIZE, and I see memory usage is always at 100% - does this mean I simply need a machine with more RAM?